# Comparing elements in individual buckets of a c++ hashmap?

Tags: c++, hashmap, unordered-map

I want to compare the size of different buckets in an `unordered_map<string, int>`, but i'm not sure how to go about doing that. Do I have to only look at the amount of buckets (`bucket_count()`) and then simply look at `bucket_size(i)`, or do I actually have to access the keys and values within each bucket and compare them? The code I have so far (below) isn't working, and I've tried modifying it ,but it still doesn't work properly. It seems like I'm doing what I need to do, but obviously not. Any help would be greatly appreciated, and thank you for your time.

```
   size_t WordFrequency::maxBucketSize() // return size of largest bucket in hash table
{
        size_t biggestBucket = wordFreq.bucket_size(0); //Something to compare to
        size_t nBuckets = wordFreq.bucket_count(); // Total number of buckets
       for(int i = 1;i<nBuckets;i++)
{
      if(wordFreq.bucket_size(i) > biggestBucket) //If # elements in bucket i > preset value
{
        biggestBucket = wordFreq.bucket_size(i); //Bucket(i) #elements= biggest
}
//loop
}
      return biggestBucket;

}
```

Comment: What is the real problem you're trying to solve? No, not the one about comparing bucket sizes, but the problem to which you believe the solution is comparing the bucket sizes, so this is why you're asking that, but your real question is something else, you just think this is the answer to it.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. I'm just trying to find the number of elements that the largest bucket has and return that number.

Comment: Can you elaborate more on how it's not working?

Comment: Yea gimme a second to get home again

Comment: @mildlyamusing1: Your code looks fine to me. In fact, I've adopted it to a sample program [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/Q4PlbQXiRxy1YO8N) and it seems to be working without issue. Ping me (with '@AndyG') when you've updated your question so I'll know to come back and check.

Comment: @AndyG okay so essentially in the program, our professor put tests in the code, so that when we compile and run, it tells us whether or not there's an issue with our program  by whether we've passed the test or not. However i'm passing all the tests except for returning the right size. The weird thing is that i'm only off by 1 for the correct answer.. Well if this isn't the problem then maybe some other part of my code that's passing the tests is.

Comment: It seems like your code is wrong (and could crash or return rubbish) if the hash table is empty (and has zero buckets).

Comment: @mildlyamusing, you need to check the number of buckets and return zero if zero, otherwise you risk accessing a non-existent first bucket as your starting biggest bucket